# convert beta estimates from linear regression to estimates you would get from logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, linear

I employed a software package on binary data thats takes a long time to run (e.g. a week) that used a multilevel mixed model (linear) instead of a logistic model; the significance is very similar between the models, and the software says its appropriate for binary data as outcome, but it doesn't give the right estimates you would get from a logistic regression.

Is it possible to correctly convert linear regression coefficients to coefficients you get from logistic regression?

Comment: Actually a crude rule of thumb says that you can divide logit estimates by 4 to make comparable to their OLS counterparts. But really there is no substitute for the real thing, espcially not if the model is complicated.